# using morning, noon and night in plural

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, articles

Which one of the following sentence is correct ?

1. How long does it take you to get to your college in the morning ?
2. How long does it take you to get to your college in the mornings ?

As getting to the college is a recurring and everday event, should i use 'morning' or 'mornings'.

And would your answer be applicable to evening and night as well ?

Answer (score 6):

It's one of idiomatic irregularities with roots in tradition of use and no true grammatical rule justification.

The correct usage is "How long does it take you to get to your college in the morning?" without plural, but still implying you talk in general, not about one specific morning.

Contrast this with a regular form:

> How long does it take you to get to your college on Monday mornings ?

Here if the "morning" was singular, it would mean next Monday. The plural makes it general. The use of singular "in the morning" is an exception from the rule.

Comment: Very concise summary of what could be seen as a tricky aspect of idiomatic usage.